# Document not found

Tags: java, google-docs, google-docs-api

I'm trying to download documents and for that working with document list
api.
Getging feed from https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full of
docuemnts and iterating over it, geting entry to download documents.
Big part of the documents are downloaded fine, but there part of them that
throws ResourceNotFoundException, here the trace:

```
at
 com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:591)
 at
 com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(GoogleGDataRequest.java:563)
  at
 com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.checkResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:552)
  at
 com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.execute(HttpGDataRequest.java:530)
  at
 com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.execute(GoogleGDataRequest.java:535)
  at
 com.google.gdata.client.media.MediaService.getMediaResource(MediaService.java:234)
  at
 com.google.gdata.client.media.MediaService.getMedia(MediaService.java:276)
  at
 com.google.gdata.client.media.MediaService.getMedia(MediaService.java:302)
```

The exception text is:

```
 com.google.gdata.util.ResourceNotFoundException: Not Found
```

And followed by Google html page.

Any thought how this one could be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what those numbers at the end of each line do, but if they are some sort of ID for the document that might be where your problem is. Because according to your error message I think the document you are trying to access does not exist.

Comment: The numbers are line numbers in Google docs api java code. The document is exists cause it was returned in the feed of all documents that are belongs to user.

Comment: Are you using Google Drive API or the now deprecated Google Docs API?

Comment: Still using deprecated Google Docs API.

Comment: Well I'm not in any way an expert at this, but it seems after reading a bit that you need to authenticate yourself, because you are getting private documents, and if you are not authenticated they will return nothing. Hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry, but doesn't help. Let's me clarify myself, after I getting the feed, I can get 99 documents and one is problematic, so I'm authenticated properly and everything is working fine, except this problematic document. Thanks