# Google Docs Folder Not Found

Tags: google-docs, google-drive-api, google-docs-api

We are using Document List API version 3.  We use two-legged OAuth and get access using permission obtained through Google Apps Marketplace. We retrieve a list of folders contained in a folder as follows:
https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/folder:[folder doc id]/contents/-/folder?xoauth_requestor_id=[user name]

We get 9 results. We retain the document ids of these folders. Later on we retrieve each folder using their document id as follows where [user name] is the same as what we used previously:
https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/[folder doc id]?xoauth_requestor_id=[user name]

We are able to get the document (folder) for 8 of the 9 but for one of them we get ResourceNotFoundException no matter when we try and no matter if we retry. We know that the folder still exists and the specified user has access to it.

This is similar in nature to the issue that someone else reported recently in:
[Document not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12448323/document-not-found)

Is this likely to be a google bug? Any suggestions of how to resolve it other than moving to Google Drive API?

Regards,
LT

Answer (score 1):

How long are you holding onto those document IDs (or really, the contentSrc URL)?  I've found that those things can expire after a few hours so you should not cache them for any length of time.

Comment: The queries are made only minutes if not seconds after the initial query is done. Besides that I don't believe that the document id for a folder or file changes over their lifetime. And that is the only thing that we retain which we use to construct the query.

Comment: Should clarify that when I say document id, it is what google refers to in their api docs as resource id.